# Client Side Javascript Manipulation

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to secure all client side requests and prevent users from excessive input entry.

For example if I have a client side operation

```
function InsertSomethingLive(ParentID){
    // Insert Code
}
```

how could I prevent the user from appending their own script like

```
function InsertSomethingLive(ParentID){
   for(i=1;i<=1000000000;i++){
    // Insert Code
  }
}
```

and say that the row has unique fields and they add additional script to run the update function like

```
function InsertSomethingLive(ParentID){
       for(i=1;i<=1000000000;i++){
        //Update Unique Field with random string
          //Call back // Insert Code
      }
    }
```

besides rate limiting on db insert is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can't stop a user mucking around in the console and calling more client side code - that's why you need to make sure you validate everything that the server receives from the client.

Comment: In your case only use UI code on the client, any code that goes beyond that should run on the server, where the end user can't reach it.

Comment: *"besides rate limiting on db insert is there any way to prevent this from happening?"* Oh, you don't want it to get that far. You want to rate-limit it earlier than that. :-) And remember that **anything** you do that limits it client-side can be bypassed, so doing those things doesn't mean you don't **also** have to handle this server-side.

Comment: @RikLewis are there any additional methods besides rate limiting that could prevent excessive entry on the server side that you know of? I was thinking of creating a new token for each db request and then passing it back, but then again they could always see the network log and pass that along in the script...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes I would rate limit on server but then I need to find the rate of which I will rate limit for each component and then limit the users entry to say x inserts per minute, and then again if they find out the rate per minute from the server then they could run a SetTimeout function to coincide with the rate

Comment: @GrantWeiss: If you're dealing with nefarious users, yes, it's always an arms race. My point above was primarily that *regardless* of what you do, you need server-side mechanisms in place.